# How can we show table names of database using dropdownlist in MVC and EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to show all the table names which are in my database into a dropdownlist.

When table is selected, I need to show another dropdownlist with columns. How can I do that?

I am using ASP.NET, MVC and EntityFramework.

**Update :** KnockoutJs: ASP.NET MVC 4 Dynamic Forms solved my dynamic dropdownlist problem.

Comment: Are you trying to save the malicious users some time?

Comment: Version of ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229514/asp-net-mvc-4-dynamic-forms

Comment: Version of MVC is MVC 4

Comment: I do a project for administrator of a company. so when they want, they send query string and show result in a gridtable. Like Sql Server management.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a **KnockoutJs** approach: [ASP.NET MVC Dynamic Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229514/asp-net-mvc-4-dynamic-forms)

Getting tables using Entity Framework:

```
using ( var ctx = new ObjectContext() )
{
    List<string> results = ctx.ExecuteStoreQuery<string>("SELECT name FROM sys.tables ORDER BY name").ToList();
}
```

Then just bind your results to a DropdownList. Knockout documentation is pretty good. [Here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/selectedOptions-binding.html) is how to bind values to select/option

Comment: ok. now I understand to add new dropdownlist. how can I call all database tables name into dropdownlist ?

Comment: The query above will return a `List<string>` which can be bound to the dropdown list.

Comment: Whatever you do, do not put variables in that SQL string to make it *dynamic*. You are already giving away column names and table names for free. This has the beginnings of a SQL Injection nightmare.

Comment: @Ric ok I need to get string query value from dropdown lists.

Comment: @James the users are administrators so they want to send query and want to see result of this query. So they should see table names and column names