# Automatically generating HTML forms in ASP.NET MVC for dynamic questionnaires

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms

I'm currently working on an ASP.NET MVC application, and I'm looking for a way to automatically generate HTML forms for a dynamic questionnaire. I have a list of over twenty questions, and I want to create a web form that allows users to answer these questions. Ideally, I'd like to avoid specifying a name for each input field individually.

Is there a recommended approach or a tool/library that can help streamline this process? My goal is to generate these forms dynamically based on the questions I have and then save the user responses to a file.

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

I just recently started studying this technology and am looking for advice

I want to automatically generate HTML form

Comment: @marc_s I don't think the OP meant *ASP.NET Web Forms* the technology, but rather that the web site should display HTML forms for the user to fill out. That's how I read the question, but I could be wrong too...

Comment: Yes. I mean HTML form.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ASP.NET MVC Dynamic Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17229514/asp-net-mvc-dynamic-forms)

Comment: OK,I updated the question to reflect that - sorry for the confusion